# Cant Understand Angle of Inclination Calculation using Accelerometer on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, math, accelerometer

```
double = rollingZ  = acceleration.x;
double = rollingX = acceleration.y;

if (rollingZ > 0.0) {
    self.centerCoordinate.inclination = atan(rollingX / rollingZ) + M_PI / 2.0; //LINE 1
} 
else if (rollingZ < 0.0) {
    self.centerCoordinate.inclination = atan(rollingX / rollingZ) - M_PI / 2.0; // LINE 2
} 
else if (rollingX < 0) {
    self.centerCoordinate.inclination = M_PI/2.0; //atan returns a radian
} 
else if (rollingX >= 0) {
    self.centerCoordinate.inclination = 3 * M_PI/2.0;
```

Im just trying to fully understand this piece of code. I'm looking to build AR apps on the iphone and this code has the function of calculating the angle of inclination of the device using the accelerometer readings.

My understanding is this:

Assuming a portrait orientation if i roll the device forward the x axis of the accelerometer increases towards a negative number of -1.0 (i.e. the device is laid flat with the screen facing up). If i tilt the device towards me the x axis value increases towards a value of 1.0 (until the device is flat facing the ground).

The y axis changes up and down its axis between -1.0 and 0.0 (0 implies the device is horizontal).

If we take some example readings say x = 0.5 (a -45 degree angle, tilting the device towards me) and y = 0.8. If i plotted this on a cartesian coordinate graph with y (rollingX as the vertical axis) and x (rollingZ as the horizontal) and draw a line between them i understand that i can use the reverse tangent function (atan) to calculate the angle. My confusion comes on line 1. I dont understand why that line adds 90 degrees (in radians) to the calculated angle given by the atan function?

I just cant seem to visualise on a graph whats going on. If someone could shed some light on this - that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the iPhone or its coordinate systems, but lines 1 and 2 are consistent with an inclination angle which is 0 when rZ=0 and rX<0, pi/2 when rZ>0 and rX=0, and -pi/2 when rz<0 and rX=0. But that's not consistent with the remaining two lines.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that these +90 degrees or -90 degrees (in case of negative rollingZ) are added to bring inclination value to widely used [Polar coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) with angle between -180 and 180 degrees.
Assuming that you have Z line projecting upward when you look at the screen of the device and Z line looking at you from the screen, the result of calculations above vill give you an angle between screen plane and horizontal plane.

Let us assume that acceleration value is positive when it is goes "inside" the device:

1) Device is in vertical position, we have rollingZ = 1, rollingX = 0. The code returns 90 degrees.

2) Device is tilted towards user. Let rollingZ be 0.7 and rollingX be -0.7. This will give us 45 degree angle.

3) Device is in upside-down position, now we have rollingZ = -1 and rollingX = 0, and it is -90 degrees.